# Parse FacebookPage Using BeautifullSoup

Tags: parsing, python-2.7, beautifulsoup

i'm searching for a name in an html page of facebook. 
if I take the file html.txt like this:

```
html = open('html.txt','r').read()
soup = BeautifulSoup(html)
```

if I search for the name with find it seems to be ok, but if i Try searching with BS i cant find anything..

```
>>>html.find("Joseph Tan")
98939
>>>html[98700:99000]
'<div class="fwn fcg"><span class="fcg"><span class="fwb"><a class="profileLink" href="https://www.facebook.com/ASD.391" data-ft="&#123;&quot;tn&quot;:&quot;l&quot;&#125;" data-hovercard="/ajax/hovercard/user.php?id=123456">Alex Tan</a></span> condivided the photo <a class="profileLink" '
>>> soup.findAll('div',{'class':'fwn fcg'})
[]
>>> soup.findAll('span',{'class':'fwb'})
[]
>>> soup.findAll('a',{'class':'profileLink'})
[]
>>>
```

Someone can help me? thanks a lot

EDIT: RE-CREATED HTML PAGE

[html page](http://android.tecnogeppetto.it/test/Tan.html)

Comment: Can you share the sample HTML code?

Comment: i have recreated the html page and correct the name. im waiting for your help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is working as below:

```
print soup.find_all('div', class_=['fwn','fcg'])

OUTPUT:

[<div class="uiHeaderActions rfloat _ohf fsm fwn fcg"><a class="_1c1m" href="#" role="button">Segna tutti come già letti</a> · <a accesskey="m" ajaxify="/ajax/messaging/composer.php" href="/messages/new/" id="u_0_8" rel="dialog" role="button">Invia un nuovo messaggio</a></div>, <div class="uiHeaderActions fsm fwn fcg"><a href="#" id="u_0_9" role="button">Segna come già letto</a> · <a href="/settings?tab=notifications&amp;section=on_facebook" target="_blank">Impostazioni</a></div>, <div class="fsm fwn fcg"><a ajaxify="/settings/language/language/?uri=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.facebook.com%2Fshares%2Fview%3Fid%3D10152555113196961&amp;source=TOP_LOCALES_DIALOG" href="#" rel="dialog" role="button" title="Usa Facebook in un'altra lingua.">Italiano</a></div>]
```

According to [==>this](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#calling-a-tag-is-like-calling-find-all) link, this is the style of how to search classes and other HTML elements using BS. Please check.

There were two problems.

**1.** The way you wrote is not matched with the link above I provided. May be you are not using updated version of BS.

**2.** There are two classes 'fwn' and 'fcg'. So you have to give their names in a list and this is how I got the output.

Same is is applicable for 'span' and 'a' as below:

```
print soup.find_all('span', class_='jewelCount')
print soup.find_all('a', class_='_awj')
```

Your given `'span'` with class `'fwb'` and given `'a'` with class `'profileLink'` was not found.Because, they are not present in the HTML.

You can check by printing all spans and a's. 
Write ***`print soup.find_all('a')`*** and **`print soup.find_all('span')`*** to check on your own.

Hope this will help, if not, write again! :)

Comment: You are most welcome Gabrio :) Its really a pleasure to get such complements for helping others... :D BTW, what is the purpose of your project? If not any problem, share with me : "sadi.research@gmail.com" I am also learning python, may be we can be use of each other by supporting :)

Comment: i have sent u a mail, i'm a newbie eheh >.< but if u can help me sometimes i will love u! and i will do the possible to help you.

Comment: i'm sorry but I still don't find the 'text' containing the name' Joseph Tan'. u can see that the two div (the first one containing 'Tan' name, and the second one found by the program) are different.. i still can't find with bs the right text...

Comment: Because "Joseph Tan" is not a part of any HTML element. You search "Joseph Tan" in your html file, and you will find this name in a <a class="profileLink"> which is commented out. Another place you will find this which is a JSON data and not an HTML element. That's why you are not finding this name. Anything beyond HTML element will not be found.

Comment: ok, i was confused by the positive return of 'html.find('Name')'. i will search information about JSON data. this will be the right way?

Comment: I think, the name is showing from JSON data in a programmatic way by Javascript. Not sure how to find it from HTML format. Because, it's place can vary from person to person. You want to parse dynamic pages on the fly, right? In that case, sorry, I can't tell you right now the exact solution. :( May be later we will discuss. :)